# Integrating Unity and Java in the cloud

Tags: java, unity-game-engine

I have this game that runs as client in desktops, and want to make all the business rules stored in a external java server, I know some java and made applications to run in jsp with spring mvc, hibernate and already made tests with sockets running in local java application, now I need to know is how to do java work in the web for the same purpose communicating with unity and vice-versa (how and where to host, how to code). Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JamesB there is not a place to ask for tutorials and this kind of stuff, you should edit you question to avoid this...

You have a lot of ways to implement the communication between a Java made server application and your Unity game client so I think your question will get some flags on to broad soon, but I'll try to set some points for you to get directions and begin your research.

One of your choices will be to build your java server as a REST API to consume with your client through json or something like this, you can take a bunch of tutorials on REST applications using Java as it is a very very common and huge explored architecture nowadays. By the Unity's side you'll need to research how to use WWW and consume json through http;

Another common way is to use sockets and RPCs (remote procedure calls), I think this is still the most common for games and again you can find a lot of tutorials on how to implement it in Unity and also in Java you need just to google this terms mentioned above and research.

The last one that I'll sugest is to avoid Java and make it using Unity's build in network API ( sure, this will apply just if you still doesn't have your server implemented and pretend to start from beginning).

There is not a best choice there is choices and the one that fits better for your project needs, to define it you have to research and understand each choice and your project itself...

How and where to host will depends on what you'll choose, if it will be a web API with REST a simple web host for Java, if it will be a Unity's based solution or Java standalone server with sockets communication you'll need a dedicated or virtual server to launch the server...

Good research.